# Define VB Excel.Chart Event that always works?

Tags: vb.net, excel, events, charts, excel-addins

Is it possible to create a Excel Chart Event (it is Calculate) that works for the Charts even if the Excel file is saved, closed and re-opened? I am using Visual Studio 2008. I think the proper way to do it may be in defining a class, but how? How do I match the Charts calculate event with the classes event?

Another way of describing is: I want to upgrade the Excel Chart to do always my own calculation on the calculate event, every time the Excel file is opened and edited. How can I make Excel remember the actions for the charts onCalculate event?

Comment: You probably need to hook into the `Workbook_Open` event to wire up the classes and their events which solves the open/save/close scheme.  Create a class for each chart/sheet.  There are not separate events for `Charts` but you can force a `Chart` to be a `Worksheet` and then you get all of the `Worksheet` events.  Is this what you are doing?  If so, it should be a simple matter of creating the class that responds to events.  This [Chip Pearson article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) is the standard I use for writing the VBA side of this.  VB.NET should be similar.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. If I get you correct you mean to identify the charts on Excel startup and re-attach the events. This can be done in my opinion, I thought about that, but since you cannot declare a Range variable for the charts that have a "with event" statement it will always be limited and you have to multiply code, etc.  Is it possible to create a component or library (don't know the exact term) which is recognized by the Excel application and which is very similar to a standart chart but has a certain different calculate event ?

Comment: You create a class module (or whatever the VB.NET equivalent is) that includes `Private WithEvents xl_sht As Worksheet` (again, VB.NET version) to catch the events for a given worksheet.  Loop through all the sheets in the `Worksheet_Open` event and create a new object (store in a array or somewhere) for each Worksheet that is a `Chart`.  Then your objects will fire with the events.  There should be no duplication of code if you use loops and an array of objects.

Comment: I doubt you can extend the `Chart` in the formal sense, but you can easily create an object which stores a reference to the `Chart` (or `Worksheet`) and then processes its events.  As a side note, you get further if you indicate **why** you want to do this.